# How to upload multi files to amazon S3 directly with the form data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

There is a form at the front-end like this to allow user insert a video list record.

```
<form action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart">
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload1
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload2
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload3
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload4
<input name="list_name" />
</form>
```

each record has at least 2 video files , and 4 files at max.

The problem is , 
From the offical tutorial,

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

The file is temporary store at my server before upload to s3 , I wonder how to upload directly to s3 in PHP ( or code-igniter )? Also post the 'list_name" to my server before start upload to s3 ?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to use multiform

```
<form action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart">
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload1
</form>

<form action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart">
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload2
</form>

<form action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart">
<input type="file" name="files[]">upload3
</form>
```

and upload using jquery upload plugin